# Selecting only unique values from collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of user objects, but need to return a list of distinct users based on User ID.

So I'm wondering is it possible to select only distinct values based on a given property of the user object?

```
Collection<User> users = serializer.Deserialize<Collection<User>>(userCollection);
```

User Object:

```
UserID
UserName
```

Thanks

Comment: Checkout this post detailing the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568347/how-do-i-use-linq-to-obtain-a-unique-list-of-properties-from-a-list-of-objects Hope this helps!

Comment: What is your collection object? System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T> or something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Distinct by property of class by linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537823/distinct-by-property-of-class-by-linq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [morelinq's](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) `DistinctBy()` method.

```
var distinctUsers = users.DistinctBy(user => user.UserID);
```

Or craft the query on your own by grouping on what you want to get the distinction and take the first item in the group.

```
var distinctUsers = users.GroupBy(user => user.UserID)
                         .Select(g => g.First());
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved via the use of a Hashset quite easily.  To do this, simply ensure that your User class has an override for both Equals and GetHashCode, and you should be set.

Edit: as DavidM mentions below, overriding equals and gethashcode for a class is only worth it if this is the normal comparison case for User objects.  If not, then Hashsets can be instantiated with custom comparers, and I would suggest going this method.

Comment: Overriding its Equals and GetHashCode implementations just for one use case doesn't sound like a good idea to me...

Comment: @DavidM fair point, but if this isn't the normal comparison case, then just use a custom comparer when instantiating the hashset.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you edit this in then that's worth a +1 from me... :)