# how delete the same string if there's same string inlistbox

Tags: vb.net

I wanna ask items in listbox. 
I've split string in listbox. So if i entered a file.txt it's split into each word.

My question is, how delete the same string  if there's same string in file.text?
and how to count each word in file.text( how many times a word appears in file.text)?

Here's my fullcode

```
     Dim s() As String = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String).ToArray()

    For Each item As String In s
        item = item.Replace(".", String.Empty)
        item = item.Replace(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ControlChars.Quote, String.Empty)
        item = item.Replace("(", String.Empty)
        item = item.Replace(")", String.Empty)
        item = item.Replace("-", String.Empty)
        item = item.Replace(",", String.Empty)

        ListBox2.Items.AddRange(item.Split(" "c))
    Next
```

Comment: Is the data of your string sorted?
Meaning, before you pass it to your string, has it been sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use LINQ to get a distinct list of items as shown here [unique-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568347/how-do-i-use-linq-to-obtain-a-unique-list-of-properties-from-a-list-of-objects).

This will get you the fastest result.