# Filter a List of Strings and select only one occurance of a string with multiple occurance

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
  var paymentTypes = _context
    .BursaryTransactions
    .Select(c => c.PaymentType)
    .ToList();

  string[] obj = paymentTypes
    .ToArray();

  var a = obj[1];
```

The  first line retrieves a list of Payment type which are in strings from `BursaryTransactions` Table 
the second line converts the list to array.

The list from the first line however contains Similar Strings for example

> 1. Post Utme
> 2. School Fee
> 3. School Fee
> 4. Post Utme
> 5. Hnd Form
> 6. Hnd Form

I want to filter these list and retrive just one occurrance of an item that appears more than once. then converts the new list to array.

Comment: `var Result = _context.BursaryTransactions.GroupBy(c => c.PaymentType).Where(group => group.Count() > 1).Select(group => group.First()).ToList();`

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [How do I use Linq to obtain a unique list of properties from a list of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568347/how-do-i-use-linq-to-obtain-a-unique-list-of-properties-from-a-list-of-objects)

Comment: Do you want to keep entries with a single occurrence? Or only get entries that appear more than once?

Comment: I just anted to retrieve only one occurance of strings with multiple occurances

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `GroupBy` and choose groups with more than `1` item:

```
   var result = _context
     .BursaryTransactions
     .GroupBy(c => c.PaymentType)        // Group By PaymentType
     .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)  // groups with more than 1 item
     .Select(group => group.First())     // we want just the 1st item of such group 
     .ToList();                          // materialized as a List<T>
```

**Edit:** to *remove duplicates* we can take `First` item from each `group`:

```
   var result = _context
     .BursaryTransactions
     .GroupBy(c => c.PaymentType)
     .Select(group => group.First()) // First().PaymentType if you want PaymentType only
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
var result = _context.BursaryTransactions.GroupBy(c => c.PaymentType)
     .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
     .Select(g => g.First())
     .ToArray();
```